# Rails: How do I make an instance method callable like validations and other gem methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am attempting to extract out some shared functionality between my models into a concern in Rails 4. While this group of functions work the same across my respective models, the models themselves have varying attributes. To accommodate this I came up with a method that takes a list of symbols and asks the object if it responds to it. If it does respond, the symbol is placed into an instance array to be iterated over by the other methods.

I could set the symbol list with a before filter, but really like the way call_backs and other gem functions are declared in models.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    include MyModule
    my_method :variable1, :variable2
end
```

My module would look something like this...

```
module MyModule
    def my_method(*optional_parameters)
        @attribute_list = []
        optional_parameters.each do |attribute|
            @attribute_list << attribute if self.respond_to? attribute
        end
    end
end
```

Currently, if called without a before filter results in an exception being thrown in Routes Updater.

I plan to eventually extract this functionality into a gem as the features grow and would really like to use it in this way.

Examples are:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :validatable
    validates :email, presence: true
    has_secure_password
end
```

Comment: what's wrong with adding a `before_` method?

Comment: I would like to be able to use the concise syntax style as I later extract this functionality. I rewrote the original post to better clarify this.

Comment: you can call a `before_` method from the `included` hook within the module. that does not influence the style in any way.

Comment: AND it's always better to make it clear than clever!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I found how to accomplish this was to send the include statement to ActiveRecord::Base

```
module MyModule
    module ClassMethods
        def my_method(an_array = [])
        end
    end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, MyModule
```

Then in the model I use the method as such...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    my_method :attribute_1, :attribute_2
end
```